# Understanding `Monomorphism` Example of Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

The [Shapeless Features Overview](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3a-shapeless-2.0.0) shows the following example:

```
import poly._

// choose is a function from Sets to Options with no type specific cases
object choose extends (Set ~> Option) {
  def apply[T](s : Set[T]) = s.headOption
}

scala> choose(Set(1, 2, 3))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> choose(Set('a', 'b', 'c'))
res1: Option[Char] = Some(a)
```

However, I don't, in m lack of experience with Shapeless, understand the difference between that and the following:

```
scala> def f[T](set: Set[T]): Option[T] = set.headOption
f: [T](set: Set[T])Option[T]

scala> f( Set(1,2,3) )
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> f( Set('a', 'b', 'c') )
res1: Option[Char] = Some(a)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The important difference here is, that `choose` is a function that can be passed around as value. You cannot make a (reasonable) value out of `f`, since Scala does not support polymorphic function values:

```
scala> val fun = f _
fun: Set[Nothing] => Option[Nothing] = <function1>
```

As you see, Scala fixes the element type to `Nothing` rendering the function useless for non-empty sets:

```
scala> fun(Set(1))
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Nothing
              fun(Set(1))
                      ^
```

This works as you would expect with the Shapeless approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The next example in the walkthrough, `pairApply `, is a nice example too. Please tell me, could `choose` have been written as a function via `def`? I'm curious why the `object ...` approach was taken.

Comment: `choose` could be written as a *method* on an object, but it couldn't be a *function* (a *value* of type `Function1`). The advantage of having it as an `object` is that you can pass it to another function without losing the genericness: `def applyToIntsAndStrings(mapper: Set ~> Option): (Option[Int], Option[String]) = (mapper(Set(1, 2), Mapper(Set("Hello"))))` and then we can call `applyToIntsAndStrings(choose)`. You can't do that with a generic `def`.