# How can I compose generic methods in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, type-systems

I'm learning Scala and have the following toy code:

```
object M {
  def isSorted[X](xs: Array[X], compare: (X, X) => Boolean): Boolean =
    xs.dropRight(1).zip(xs.drop(1)).forall(Function.tupled(compare))

  def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C) : A => (B => C) =
    (a) => (b) => f(a, b)
}
```

My goal is to call it like:

```
M.curry(M.isSorted)(Array(1,2,3))((a, b) => a < b)
```

But I receive the error:

```
scala> M.curry(M.isSorted)(Array(1,2,3))
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Int(1)
  required: Nothing
  M.curry(M.isSorted)(Array(1,2,3))
```

Let's back up and look at the type of the curried function:

```
scala> M.curry(M.isSorted)
res2: Array[Nothing] => (((Nothing, Nothing) => Boolean) => Boolean) = <function1>
```

That's no good. It wants an `Array[Nothing]` but there can be no instances of `Nothing`.

I understand at some point I will need to introduce a constraint so the compiler can prove that the expression `a < b` is allowable; that is, that `a` and `b` are Ordered. But I don't know where I would put the constraint. `curry` is perfectly generic; the constraint doesn't belong there. `isSorted` knows nothing about the implementation of `compare`, so it doesn't belong there either.

The closest I've gotten to having it working is with `def isSorted[X >: Any]`

```
scala> M.curry(M.isSorted)(Array(1,2,3))((a, b) => a < b)
<console>:8: error: value < is not a member of Any
  M.curry(M.isSorted)(Array(1,2,3))((a, b) => a < b)
                                                ^

scala> M.curry(M.isSorted)(Array(1,2,3))((a: Int, b: Int) => a < b)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
  found   : (Int, Int) => Boolean
  required: (Any, Any) => Boolean
  M.curry(M.isSorted)(Array(1,2,3))((a: Int, b: Int) => a < b)
                                                          ^
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Just to add to the other answer, if you need to pass a function around *and keep it generic while you pass it*, you have to use a trick like [shapeless poly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206295/understanding-monomorphism-example-of-shapeless).

Comment: @Pater Winton Yes things like `shapeless` can make life simpler in some cases... but for now focus on understanding Scala and functional programming itself. Don't think about wandering to Shapeless land for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object M {
  def isSorted[X](xs: Array[X], compare: (X, X) => Boolean): Boolean =
    xs.dropRight(1).zip(xs.drop(1)).forall(Function.tupled(compare))

  def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C) : A => (B => C) =
    (a) => (b) => f(a, b)
}
```

Well... I don't think this is the best way to define these functions but in this case, since these are generic functions so you need to provide them with a type when calling.

As @dk14 has pointed out in his comment... `M.sorted` can not get type info because Scala lacks support for polymorphic lambdas.... which simply means no generics in anonymous functions.

So you need to do this for this particular case.

```
M.curry( M.isSorted[Int] )( Array(1,2,3) ) ( (a , b) => a < b )
```

Comment: the solution is right, but it's not connected to type erasure  as it has nothing to do with runtime types - `M.isSorted` here is just a short form of `M.isSorted _` - eta-expansion in Scala doesn't infer generic type - but it's just Scala's restriction - Haskell for example will infer generic type A here, same for `M.curry` and finally bind `Int` from `Array(1,2,3)` argument - but scala can't do that - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652463/1-listnothing-in-foldleft

Comment: @dk14 thanks for clearing one more mis-conception of mine. This is exactly why I love Stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Thanks @SarveshKumarSingh, that works. "I don't think this is the best way to define these functions but in this case." How would you do it? What is the "scala way"?

Comment: I'm coming from a scheme background, so it would be natural to do
something like [this](https://gist.github.com/wintonpc/dc7c6e5a829320d69faf).

The original reason for currying was I found Scala
wouldn't infer the argument types of the `compare` lambda if I passed
it directly as the second argument to `isSorted`. As noted [here](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html)